# mySQL query takes longer after 3rd INNER JOIN added

Tags: mysql

Problem when adding an additional join to a query.

This query take almost a full minute to run:

```
SELECT * FROM jos_mls AS mls
        INNER JOIN jos_activeagents AS active ON mls.MSTLISTBRD = active.AGENTUID
        INNER JOIN jos_agents AS agents ON active.AGENTUID = agents.AGTBRDIDMM
        INNER JOIN jos_clstmp AS cl ON mls.MSTMLSNO = cl.MSTMLSNO
    WHERE mls.MSTACTSTA != 'Inactive'
    AND mls.MSTLISTDT >= SUBDATE(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)
```

If I omit the line `INNER JOIN jos_clstmp AS cl ON mls.MSTMLSNO = cl.MSTMLSNO`, it takes less than a second.

The jos_clstmp table is only two columns.  A key and a timestamp.  I wouldn't think it would add that much to the process, but it's killing it.

Comment: Is there a key on `MSTMLSNO` on both tables?

Comment: Are there any indexes on jos_clstmp?

Comment: Index, duh.  I know I forgot something.  Sorry, rusty mySQL skills.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
INNER JOIN jos_clstmp AS cl ON mls.MSTMLSNO = cl.MSTMLSNO
```

Do both columns

```
mls.MSTMLSNO and cl.MSTMLSNO
```

have a key/index?

Comment: Both of those columns are primary keys, but I don't think I defined an index for cl.MSTMLSNO.